# How do I use this indirect relationship?

Tags: orm, relationship, cakephp-2.1

I'm working on incorporating a reputation system into my site, similar to SO. Here is how it is structured:

User hasMany Project
User hasMany Answer
Project hasMany Rating
Answer hasMany Rating
Rating belongsTo Project where Rating.parent_type = Project
Rating belongsTo Answer where Rating.parent_type = Answer

Rating's value field will be a number between 1 and 5. The user should gain +10 for every 5-star review, +5 for every 4-star review, and +1 for every 3-star review. The way I currently have it set up is this: a recalcRep($id) action in the UsersController (along with other actions in other controllers, when necessary) calls the calcRep($id) method inside the User model, which is supposed to calculate the reputation of a user with an id of $id.

```
public function calcRep($id) {
        $rep = 0;

        $data = $this->Rating->find('all'); //does not work, because it is not directly associated
        foreach($data as $rating) {
            if(($rating['Rating']['parent_type'] == 'Project' && $rating['Project']['user_id']==$id) or ($rating['Rating']['parent_type'] == 'Answer' && $rating['Answer']['user_id']==$id)) {
                if($rating['Rating']['value']==5) {
                    $rep += 10;
                } else if($rating['Rating']['value']==4) {
                    $rep += 5;
                } else if($rating['Rating']['value']==3) {
                    $rep += 2;
                }
            }
        }
        $data['User']['reputation'] = $rep;
        $this->save($data);
    }
```

I may be approaching this in completely the wrong way, but I can't figure out how to find all the ratings that belong to any of the children of a specific user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think cakePHP requires that if you're going to call a model definition from a controller, the controller name has to be the same as the model, like since you're calling `$this->Rating`, the class calling it would need to be `RatingController` or something like that. Your best bet is to call the `find('all')` inside your `RatingController` and store it in a temporary variable that you pass to `calcRep()` i.e.:

```
<?php
class RatingsController extends AppController {
    function calcRep($id) {
        $rep = 0;

        $data = $this->Rating->find('all'); //should work now, as you're calling it from the defined controller
        foreach($data as $rating) {
            if(($rating['Rating']['parent_type'] == 'Project' && $rating['Project']['user_id']==$id) or ($rating['Rating']['parent_type'] == 'Answer' && $rating['Answer']['user_id']==$id)) {
                if($rating['Rating']['value']==5) {
                    $rep += 10;
                } else if($rating['Rating']['value']==4) {
                    $rep += 5;
                } else if($rating['Rating']['value']==3) {
                    $rep += 2;
                }
            }
        }
        $data['User']['reputation'] = $rep;
        $this->save($data);
    }

}

?>
```

I believe there is also a `loadModel()` function? Perhaps if you `loadModel('Rating')` beforehand it would work.

It seems the PHP interpretation model for cakePHP doesn't let you do this inside of a model though, as what you're trying to do is Ideally suited for a controller.

Comment: Then it seems like I would run into  more issues. I want the result to be that the reputation value is cached in the 'reputation' field in the users table. Also, eventually ratings are not going to be the only thing affecting reputation, so it seems like it would make more sense to store it in User.

Comment: you're still manipulating data here, so it should be in a controller. If you want to take information from the rating table, manipulate it, and store it in the User table, then load the User inside the Controller you're calling this from. It must be a controller or you must load the models first. You should be able to call `$this->loadModel('User');` and then `$this->User->save($data);` if you want to store it in the User table